# What is the best way to export a Blender Nurbs object to Rhino or Solidworks for mold production?

Tags: printing, solidworks, nurbs, rhino3d, mold

My question would be to model in blender and send the object to rhino or solidworks, for mold production.
Would this be possible in nurbs?

thank you for any help,

thanks
Edward

When I export from Blender (.obj) to Rhino and export in (.xt) to solidworks the object arrives with a defect.

Any idea how to export with less errors?

thank you for any help,

thanks
Edward